# Передача указателя на void функцию в качестве аргумента

Tags: c, функции

Вечно путаю синтаксис...

Есть функция:

```
void DoSMTH(int a1, int b1){
    // Делаю что-то с a1 и b1
}
```

Есть функция Вызывальщик

```
int DoSMTHwithSMTH(/* Что здесь? */){   
    /* ЗДЕСЬ ВЫЗОВ DoSMTH(a2, b2) */
}
```

Главный поток:

```
int main(){
    return DoSMTHwithSMTH(/* ЧТО ЗДЕСЬ? */)
}
```

P.S. Код вверху - пример, если хотите - можете привести свой

P.P.S. Нашел пример, но в нем отсутствуют аргументы у передаваемой функции

```
// Прототипы функций
void main_func(void (*)());
// Главное, чтобы функции, которые будут передаваться по указателю,
// имели общий вид прототипа (тип возвращаемого значения и тип принимаемых
// параметров)
void f1();
void f2();
void f3();

int main()
{
    const int N = 3;

    // Массив указателей на функции с общим прототипом
    // Сразу инициализируется соответствующими функциями
    void (*func_arr[N])() = {f1, f2, f3};

    // В цикле передаём основной функции элементы нашего массива
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        main_func(func_arr[i]);

    return 0;
}

// Основная функция просто вызывает переданную
void main_func(void (*f)())
{
    // Есть два способа вызова. Традиционный и с явным указанием того,
    // что вызывается функция, переданная по указателю.
    // (*f)();
    f();
}

void f1()
{
    std::cout << "Call f1..." <<std::endl;
}

void f2()
{
    std::cout << "Call f2..." <<std::endl;
}

void f3()
{
    std::cout << "Call f3..." <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Что такое a2 и b2? Откуда они берутся? И почему речь вообще идёт об указателях на функцию?

Comment: @AnT Это просто аргуметы, которые генерятся в DoSMTHwithSMTH

Comment: @AnT Потому что требуется передать ссылку на функцию DoSMTH в функцию DoSMTHwithSMTH. Знаю, что проще объявить в main.h, но я пишу менеджер процессов для своей ОС, потому нельзя их четко объявить в main.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите передать указатель на функцию как аргумент функции, то либо определите прототип, либо просто сам прототип опишите аргументом:

Прототип:

```
typedef void(*my_callback_t)(int, int);

void DoSMTH(int a1, int b1){
    // Делаю что-то с a1 и b1
}

int DoSMTHwithSMTH(my_callback_t cb)
{   
    cb(a2, b2);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    return DoSMTHwithSMTH(DoSMTH);
}
```

Or:

```
void DoSMTH(int a1, int b1){
    // Делаю что-то с a1 и b1
}

int DoSMTHwithSMTH(void(*cb)(int, int))
{   
    cb(a2, b2);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    return DoSMTHwithSMTH(DoSMTH);
}
```

Comment: А прототип точно можно использовать в C99 без библиотек?

Comment: Да, вот вам [пример](https://ideone.com/hISwOT).

Comment: Огромное спасибо. P.S> Думал, что прототипы - это C++ only