# Передать ссылку на функцию в структуру

Tags: c, функции

В продолжение к [ЭТОМУ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1000127/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-void-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0/1000129?noredirect=1#comment1692014_1000129) вопросу.

Как добавить ссыку на функцию в структуру?

Я попробовал так, но выдает ошибку

```
struct SimpleProcess{   // Одиночный процесс 

    unsigned char Priority;         // Приоритет
    unsigned char SecurityLevel;    // Уровень безопасности
    void(*)(int, ...) Function;     // Функция 

}
```

Ошибка:

```
error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘)’ token
         void(*)(int, ...) Function;     // Функция
```

Comment: Только это называется не ссылкой, а указателем, если что...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам стоило посмотреть вот на это:  `int DoSMTHwithSMTH(void(*cb)(int, int))`.

Где `cb` — название переменной.

Все просто:

```
typedef struct SimpleProcess
{   // Одиночный процесс 

    unsigned char Priority;         // Приоритет
    unsigned char SecurityLevel;    // Уровень безопасности
    void(*Function)(int, ...);     // Функция 

} SimpleProcess;
```

Comment: А вызывать как? SimpleProcess.Function() ?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Огроменное Спасибо!

Comment: А как присвоить?

Comment: `simpleProcess.Function = someFunction`?

Comment: Вот вам [пример](https://ideone.com/ahRTxm).

Comment: Огромное спасибо